# Why kafka failed to create deliver client for orderer on multi node fabric network?

Tags: apache-kafka, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to install a HLF (v2) network on 2 physical machines. 
Machine 1:

- 1 orderer 2 peers 2 couchdb 2 zookeeper 2 kafka

Machine 2:

- 1 orderer 2 peers 2 couchdb 1 zookeeper 2 kafka

The containers is running on both machines.

However, when i try to create channel on machine 1

```
peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
```

I receive this error:
Error: failed to create deliver client for orderer: orderer client failed to connect to orderer.example.com:7050: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded

```
docker logs orderer.example.com -f
```

output:

```
FO 00c [channel: byfn-sys-channel] Setting up the topic for this channel...
2020-06-09 20:10:31.316 UTC [orderer.consensus.kafka.sarama] Open -> DEBU 00d ClientID is the default of 'sarama', you should consider setting it to something application-specific.
2020-06-09 20:10:31.320 UTC [orderer.consensus.kafka.sarama] withRecover -> DEBU 00e Failed to connect to broker kafka0.example.com:9092: dial tcp 172.20.0.5:9092: connect: connection refused
2020-06-09 20:10:31.321 UTC [orderer.consensus.kafka.sarama] Open -> DEBU 00f ClientID is the default of 'sarama', you should consider setting it to something application-specific.
2020-06-09 20:10:31.323 UTC [orderer.consensus.kafka.sarama] withRecover -> DEBU 010 Failed to connect to broker kafka1.example.com:9092: dial tcp 172.20.0.9:9092: connect: connection refused
2020-06-09 20:10:31.323 UTC [orderer.consensus.kafka.sarama] Open -> DEBU 011 ClientID is the default of 'sarama', you should consider setting it to something application-specific.
2020-06-09 20:10:31.342 UTC [orderer.consensus.kafka.sarama] withRecover -> DEBU 012 Failed to connect to broker kafka2.example.com:9092: dial tcp: lookup kafka2.example.com on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host
2020-06-09 20:10:31.342 UTC [orderer.consensus.kafka.sarama] Open -> DEBU 013 ClientID is the default of 'sarama', you should consider setting it to something application-specific.
2020-06-09 20:10:31.355 UTC [orderer.consensus.kafka.sarama] withRecover -> DEBU 014 Failed to connect to broker kafka3.example.com:9092: dial tcp: lookup kafka3.example.com on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host
2020-06-09 20:10:36.355 UTC [orderer.consensus.kafka.sarama] Open -> DEBU 015 ClientID is the default of 'sarama', you should consider setting it to something application-specific.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure a unique "clientid" per consumer in Sarama.

Kafka has the concept of "consumer groups" and "consumers" (aka clientid).  Each consumer must have a unique id within the consumer group. Kafka will assign partition(s) to consumers. Kafka will keep track of the offset position of all consumers using the consumer group.

Comment: could you enlighten me please about your answer? It is the first time i am trying to use kafka. When you talk about groups, do you mean something like in configtx.yaml:                                                                                                                  Kafka:
        Brokers:
            - IP_host1 :9092
            - IP_host1 :9092
            - IP_host2:9092
            - IP_host2:9092

Comment: I'm not an expert with Sarama, but a quick google makes it look like this is the file you need to update: https://github.com/Shopify/sarama/blob/master/config.go

Each instance of Sarama needs to have a unique clientId